# What's the correct way of implementing a data access manager with support for multiple connections so that it can be injected?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-core

I am developing a WebAPI in .Net Core 2.2. I need a custom Data Access object to query data. However, I need different connections for different tasks. What's the best approach for this using DI and .NetCore IOptions pattern?

I have tried having all connections in the DAL object and specifying the connection id when invoking the method. I have the option of having different classes for each one, but I guess that's overkill.

So let's suppose I have this into appsettings.json

```
"DatabaseMetaConfiguration": {
  "MappingDb": {
    "DNS": "pgc.app.corp.acme.com",
    "Database": "mappings",
    "User": "mappings_user",
    "Pass": "111",
    "SSL": "SSL Mode=Prefer; Trust Server Certificate=true"
  },
  "StatusDb": {
    "DNS": "pgc.app.corp.acme.com",
    "Database": "status",
    "User": "status_user",
    "Pass": "222",
    "SSL": "SSL Mode=Prefer; Trust Server Certificate=true"
  },
  "MasterDb": {
    "DNS": "pgc.app.corp.acme.com",
    "Database": "master",
    "User": "master_user",
    "Pass": "333",
    "SSL": "SSL Mode=Prefer; Trust Server Certificate=true"
  },
  "BookDb": {
    "DNS": "pgc.app-books.corp.acme.com",
    "Database": "book",
    "User": "book_user",
    "Pass": "444",
    "SSL": "SSL Mode=Prefer; Trust Server Certificate=true"
  }
}
```

Then the POCO options classes:

```
public class PostgreSqlDatabaseMetaConfigurations : Dictionary<string, PostgreSqlDatabaseMetaConfiguration> { }

public class PostgreSqlDatabaseMetaConfiguration
{
    public string Database { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Pass { get; set; }
    public string DNS { get; set; }
    public string SSL { get; set; }
    public int Timeout { get; set; }
    public int CommandTimeout { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get { [...] } }
}
```

And the actual DAL class:

```
public class PostgreSqlManager : IDisposable, ISqlManager
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, NpgsqlConnection> _connections;
    private readonly ILogger<PostgreSqlManager> _logger;

    public PostgreSqlManager(IOptionsMonitor<PostgreSqlDatabaseMetaConfigurations> optionsAccessor, ILogger<PostgreSqlManager> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        var dbConfigurations = optionsAccessor.CurrentValue;
        if (dbConfigurations == null || !dbConfigurations.Any())
            _logger.LogWarning("No connections configured!");

        // Create a dictionary of connections, indexed by the connection names
        _connections = dbConfigurations.ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => new NpgsqlConnection(c.Value.ConnectionString));
    }

    // So, a sample method would be...

    public async Task<long> ExecuteScalarAsync(string connectionId, string commandText, List<DbParameter> parameters = null, CommandType commandType = CommandType.Text)
    {
        using (var command = GetDbCommand(_connections[connectionId], commandText, parameters, commandType))
        {
            try
            {
                await command.Connection.OpenAsync();
                return (Int64)await command.ExecuteScalarAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Exception on ExecuteScalarAsync({0})", commandText);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                command.CloseCommand();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, in ConfigureServices I have this lines:

```
services.AddSingleton<ISqlManager, PostgreSqlManager>();
services.Configure<PostgreSqlDatabaseMetaConfigurations>(configuration.GetSection("DatabaseMetaConfiguration"));
```

(Sorry for the big chunks of code, I wanted it to be clear.)

Now, if I want to make use of the DAL service class, I need to inject an `ISqlManager` in my controller. Then, on each method call, I need to specify which connection I want.

Now here is my question. If I know beforehand which connection I need in each controller class, how can I specify it so that each controller uses the connection I know it will need?

Better yet, can I setup several different instances of the DAL class into DI container, each one with a different connection, and let each controller class decide which one to use?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using AddScoped to register your PostgreSqlManager. This will keep the object alive for the duration of the web request.

You could then do something like

```
public interface IBookRepository
{
   Book GetByISBN(string isbn);
   Add(Book book)
   Delete(Book book)
}

public class BookRepository: IBookRepository
{
  private ISqlManager _sqlManager;

  public BookRepository(ISqlManager sqlManager)
  {
    _sqlManager = sqlManager;
  }

  public Book GetByISBN(string isbn)
  {
    var rows = _sqlManager.GetRows("BooksDb", "exec uspGetBookByISBN", CreateStringParam(isbn));

    // convert rows into book object(s)

   return books.FirstOrDefault();

  }

}
```

Now you can register one or more repository per database and register e.g.

services.AddScoped();

And in your controller inject the ones you need.

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
  private IBookRepository _bookRepository;
  private IStatusRepository _statusRepository;
  public MyController(IBookRepository bookRepository, IStatusRepository statusRepository)
  {
    _bookRepository = bookRepository; 
    _statusRepository = statusRepository
  }
}
```

The DI container will make sure that your dependencies are resolved correctly as long as they have been registered.

Comment: Looks like it's a good idea. And what about performance? Will it be costly to instantiate a manager on each request?

Comment: No I don't see any reason why it would be.